# Thickness of lines in a table in LYX

Tags: tables, lyx

I would like to increase the thickness of the top and the bottom lines of the attached table in Lyx. I tried command,

```
\newcommand{\hthickcline}{4}
```

as shown in the attached Lyx file but it does not work

[image].
Regards, Ahmed.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this command, but in your source-code, you can load the `boldline` package, which defines `\hlineB{x}`, meaning `x times  default arrayrule width` (0.4pt, but it may be changed), `\clineB{m-n}{x}` and `V{x}` in the preamble of the tables, in replacement of `|` for vertical rules.

Alternatively, the `makecell` package, among many other useful things defines `Xhline{some thickness (with unit)}` and `\Xcline{m-n}{thickness}`. It defines nothing for vertical rules.

A third solution is the `booktabs` package, which defines `\toprule`, and `bottomrule` with  thickness `\heavyrulewidth` (default `0.08em`), `midrule` (thickness `\lightrulewidth`, default `0.05em`) and `\cmidrule` (thickness `\cmidrulewidth`, default `0.03em`). Additionally, the rules have some vertical padding around them.

*Edit:*

According to G.M., Lyx supports booktabs under the name `Formal table` (it is an option to check in the table properties).

Comment: The third command looks like a good answer. You could add to it that LyX supports booktabs under the name "Formal table" (it is an option to check in the table properties). Ahmed, I would recommend formatting your table as a formal table first (see the booktabs manual for recommendations). Then if you still want to tweak it you can change the lengths that Bernard described.

Comment: @G.M.: I've added your comment to my answer. Note there are some troubles with booktabs when colouring cells in table (white strips appear at bottom and top of coloured cells).